# Getting iPhone Auto-Lock Setting

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, xamarin.ios

Is it possible to ask the OS via code if the Auto-Lock and or Password Lock is enabled on the device?

A secure app I am making needs to warn the user if these are not set.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently this is not possible (used to be prior to 5.0).  You can consider implementing a lock screen for the application.